# Extension for Chrome or Firefox to edit pages?

Tags: google-chrome, browser-extension

Is there an extension like Firebug/Chrome "inspect element", that allows one to easily add nodes to a page, and save the changes back to a file? It strikes me that this would be nice way to develop pages.

Comment: Why should this be implemented as a browser extension, rather than an editor?

Comment: So one can see the changes immediately.

Comment: If you edit javascript files in Chrome Dev Tools, you can right click and choose "Save" to save them. It's odd that you can't do the same with HTML files -- I wonder why?

Answer (score -1):

You can edit HTML from Chrome's Developer Tools (Wrench key -> Tools -> Developer Tools). Just right click and 'Edit as HTML'. When finish, copy it with right click -> 'Copy as HTML'.

Comment: I can type just as well in my editor. I also want to save the changes.